# Calculating Space Complexity of Stack Search

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack, big-o

having a bit of issues understanding space complexity for a method.

In the case of a stack and a search function, I understand that time complexity is `O(n)` since it depends on the amount of elements in the stack. What would the space complexity be in this case? Would it be `O(1)` since there are no variables or does the search consume extra memory based off the amount of elements and cause it to be `O(n)`?

Ex Function:

```
return stack.search(item) != -1
```

Edit:

Here is the built in function in question:

```
public synchronized int search(Object o) {
    int i = lastIndexOf(o);

    if (i >= 0) {
        return size() - i;
    }
    return -1;
}
public synchronized int lastIndexOf(Object o, int index) {
    if (index >= elementCount)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " >= "+ elementCount);

    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Can someone provide a step by step breakdown of how to calculate space complexity for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither time nor space complexity appears to be documented in the Javadoc for [`Stack.search`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#search%28java.lang.Object%29).

However, a brief look at the OpenJDK source code shows that [it's implemented in terms of `Vector.lastIndexOf()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/Stack.java#l131), which in turn [is a linear scan with just a couple of helper variables](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/Vector.java#l441).  So yes, O(1) space in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the point of O(n) you mentioned. Stack is both O(1) time for storing(push) and O(1) for retrieving(pop).

There is no operation defined as search for proper stack data structure. Stack simply works in a Last In First Out fashion. When you add a new item, you add it on top, when you retrieve an item, you only have one option, the top. So, both push and pop operations have time complexity of O(1).

To talk about space complexity, we need to know what the problem is. If you need to store n items in stack same time, then space complexity is O(n). But you can store n items, in O(1) space too. You can push and pop every item, therefore you use only 1 space.

So what's happening in this Java implementation?

It seems they simply implemented search method, just in case, maybe someone would ever need, I don't know. But it simply violates stack contract.

If you use a search on stack, then it's time complexity is O(n) and it's no longer a stack actually. Space complexity is O(1), you guessed right. It would only use 1 extra variable, it doesn't scale up with stack size.

Edit: Sorry, I didn't realize this is a Java's stack implementation specific question. I'm editing my answer to cover Java implementation.

Comment: Hmm: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#search%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: This implementation doesn't change the stack theory. I checked the search() method on your link, using this method violates stack data structure, therefore it's not stack anymore. When you define a data structure, you put some restrictions, if you don't obey these restrictions, then your algorithmic complexity changes. If you use a stack to get time complexity of O(1), then you can't make O(n) searches on the stack, if you do, then it's not a stack(or in different words, time complexity is not O(1) anymore)

Comment: What do you mean by "it violates stack data structure"?  Certainly you shouldn't be using a stack if you want to do searches, but that doesn't change the fact that Java's `Stack` has a `search` method, and that is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Do you know what is a stack? Data structures are tailored for needs. Stack is tailored for uses which doesn't need search, that's how it promises O(1) time complexity! For example, callstacks, why they use stacks for storing call infos instead of arrays or linked lists, or else? Because they only need to get last element, always. They don't need expensive operations, so they don't use expensive operations. Arrays support random access, which is expensive. Shortly, if you need a book, would you buy a printing house, or would go to a printing house to buy a book?