# Will using remove(item) from Vector class on a Stack maintain O(1) pop, peek, push run times?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack, big-o

In my previous question ([Calculating Space Complexity of Stack Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479939/calculating-space-complexity-of-stack-search/34480115#34480115)), someone said you aren't supposed to use search(item) or remove(item) in a stack. The reason I have chosen a stack is because it seems easier to pop rather than access array.length-1 if you are consistently going for LIFO.

Would using these non traditional stack operations impact O(1) runtimes of pop, peek, and push?

Comment: No, if you are using java.util.Stack using search or remove won't impact the runtimes of other methods, though those methods probably run very slowly

Comment: pop, peek, and push (assuming the data structure works like a traditional stack) will be no different. It only impacts removing that specific element although like you've heard, that basically breaks the stack contract and isn't reliable in a general way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will using remove(item) from Vector class on a Stack maintain O(1) pop, peek, push run times?

It depends how `remove` is implemented and what the underlying implementation of the Stack is (in this case, you're saying it's a Java `Vector`, so it depends on how `Vector.remove` is implemented).

If the underlying data structure is linked-list based, then we must iterate to the position we want to remove, which is an `O(n)` operation, where `n` is the length of the vector. If the underlying data structure is array based, then it's an O(1) index to get to the spot we want to remove. The catch here is if we want to remove an element at the beginning of the array, then we will have to shift every element over to the left, which is a linear time operation. Therefore, this too has an `O(n)` worst-case.

In Java, the `Vector` class is implemented using an array as the underlying structure. This means that if the `Stack.pop` implementation looks for the last element in the `Vector`, the `Vector` will not have to shift any elements, and therefore the runtime is O(1).

The tl;dr for this question is "sometimes".

> Would using these non traditional stack operations impact O(1) runtimes of pop, peek, and push?

`search` will certainly be an O(n) operation (i.e., it is iterating through looking for the element you asked for).

To answer this question, using these non-traditional stack operations will *not* impact the O(1) runtime of `pop`, `peek`, and `push`. That said, `search` and `remove` themselves do have runtimes of O(n).

Comment: Thanks for answering this question as well! On the note of search and remove (as well as size), how would you calculate their space complexities? I edited another one of my questions with the exact function that java uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479939/calculating-space-complexity-of-stack-search/34480115#34480115

Comment: So, the key with space complexity, as I like to think of it, is that if you have anything that could hold N elements (hashtable or key-value pairs included) will have a space complexity of O(N), which is the worst case -- i.e. that there are an arbitrary, N, number of elements in the structure. If it's any sort of primitive, it will have a constant space complexity. `String`s are `char` arrays, so technically they're O(N) in space. Lastly, the only time you really see O(N^2) is when you deal with matrices or multidimensional arrays. Again, technically an array of strings is multidimensional...

Comment: Is the answer to the search complexity incorrect then? O(1)? The for loop in the else is making me think it could be O(n)?

Comment: No, he is correct. The `search` method itself contains an `int`, which is constant space, and they are not introducing any new lists, arrays, hashtables, or any other linear data structure. A `for` loop does not contribute to space complexity, but it _does_ contribute to time complexity. The only contributors to space complexity are variables/objects.

Comment: I see. I assume the same would apply to stack.size() since there are no new variables being introduced. How would shifting in the case of stack.remove()/vector.remove() come into play with space complexity? I guess it comes down to whether the shifting uses the same memory or whether it takes memory to perform the shifts?

Comment: The same does apply to `stack.size()`. Shifting in theory does not contribute to space complexity because you are simply moving `arr[i]` to `arr[i-1]`, which should be constant. In most implementations, the shift does a `memcopy` (or somesuch -- see line 670 in http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Vector-source.html). If the `memcopy` uses a buffer, then the shift will be O(n) space complexity; however, after the copy the buffer is destroyed. The space complexity remains O(n) because for the operation to occur, there needed to be O(n) (in the worst case) space.

Comment: So, it isn't the shifting itself that introduces the space complexity, but rather the memcopy. In order to perform a memcopy operation there needs to be O(n) available initially even if each time the buffer is destroyed. Is this correct? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks! You've really helped me understand space complexity. Happy New Years to you!